# ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump expected 4 but found 2 (indentation)

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = '''
---
project: ''
project_lead: &ptl
    name: ''
    company: ''
    email: ''
    id: ''
    timezone: ''
primary_contact: *ptl
committers:
    - <<: *ptl
    - name: ''
      email: ''
      company: ''
      id: ''
      timezone: ''
    - name: ''
      email: ''
      company: ''
      id: ''
      timezone: ''
'''


DATA = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str, version=None, preserve_quotes=True)
indent = 4
block_seq_indent = 2
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(DATA, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=True, indent=indent,
                            block_seq_indent=block_seq_indent)
```

Output:

```
project: ''
project_lead: &ptl
    name: ''
    company: ''
    email: ''
    id: ''
    timezone: ''
primary_contact: *ptl
committers:
  - <<: *ptl
  - name: ''
    email: ''
    company: ''
    id: ''
    timezone: ''
  - name: ''
    email: ''
    company: ''
    id: ''
    timezone: ''
```

ISSUE:

```
foo.yaml|10 col 3 error| wrong indentation: expected 4 but found 2 (indentation)
```

If I increase

```
block_seq_indent = 4
```

the values following it (email, company, id, timezone) don't follow its indentation.

Is my source YAML 'wrong'? Can I work around this? The ruamel module is great, and I'm able to add values programmatically, but I can't seem to get valid YAML in my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input has four positions indent on the (nested) block mapping that is the value for `project_lead`, and it has six indent on the sequence that is the value for `committers`, with an offset for the dash of four (in sequences the indent is counted to the beginning of the sequence element).

This does indeed go wrong if you use the old API as you do, but with the new API (and the appropriate values), you can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from cStringIO import StringIO

yaml_str = '''\
---
project: ''
project_lead: &ptl
    name: ''
    company: ''
    email: ''
    id: ''
    timezone: ''
primary_contact: *ptl
committers:
    - <<: *ptl
    - name: ''
      email: ''
      company: ''
      id: ''
      timezone: ''
    - name: ''
      email: ''
      company: ''
      id: ''
      timezone: ''
'''

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=6, offset=4)
yaml.explicit_start = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
buf = StringIO()
yaml.dump(data, buf)
assert buf.getvalue() == yaml_str
```

without getting an error.

Please note:

- the `default_flow_style=True` has no effect in your example, they only would affect new mappings and lists, and I am not sure you want to do that for all added values.
- I added `yaml.explicit_start = True` to get the leading `---`
- Your example starts with an empty newline (directly after the `'''`, that is as if you did  `yaml_str = '\n---\nproject: .....'`). You cannot really get that output with `ruamel.yaml()` from a data structure, hence the backslash in my `yaml_str`.
- although this might be considered a bug in the old API, I have no intention of fixing it.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!